# How can the output of my formula span across multiple cells?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, countif

In excel, I want to create a formula that has output a,b,c,d,e in cells Bx, Bx+1, Bx+2, Bx+3, Bx+4 respectively, if the cell value is duplicated 5 times (in this case '1' and '3' appear 5 times), and has output b,c,d,e in cells Bx, Bx+1, Bx+2, Bx+3 if the cell value is duplicated 4 times (in this case '2' appears 4 times).

In the below, column B is the output

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 1 | b |
| 1 | c |
| 1 | d |
| 1 | e |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | c |
| 2 | d |
| 2 | e |
| 3 | a |
| 3 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 3 | d |
| 3 | e |

How can I create this formula in Excel?

I suppose it'd be some variation of this formula:

=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)=5, (paste values a,b,c,d,e in cells B1, B2, B3, B4, B5), (paste values b,c,d,e in cells B1, B2, B3, B4))

However I don't know how to fill in the value_if_true and value_if_false part of the above formula

Comment: So 4 and 5 are the only two possibilities for the number of occurrences of a given entry?

Comment: You can try a nested `IF` Statement.  Test the count to see where you start. `IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$15,A2) = 5,IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,"A",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=2,"B",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=3,"C",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=4,"D","E")))),IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$15,A2) = 4,IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=1,"B",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=2,"C",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)=3,"D","E")))))`

Answer (score 1):

```
=LET(a,TOCOL(A:A,1),
     b,MMULT(--(TOROW(a)=UNIQUE(a)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(a),,,0)),
DROP(
     REDUCE("", b,
     LAMBDA(x,  y,
     VSTACK(x,
            SORT(
                 INDEX({"e","d","c","b","a"},
                 SEQUENCE(y)))))),
     1))
```

This formula first stores a counter for each unique value in column A.
Then it creates an array of indexing `e` to `a` with a sequence of the counter (so if less than 5 are found, it will list the number of strings starting from `e`). This result is stacked to the previous result and iterates to the end.

Answer (score 1):

Another take on this, using Frequency to get counts for each number and without using a lambda:

```
=LET(numbers,TOCOL(A:A,1),
 rows,COUNT(numbers),
 letters,"abcde",
 unique,UNIQUE(numbers),
 freq,DROP(FREQUENCY(numbers,unique),-1),
 indices,SEQUENCE(rows)-XMATCH(numbers,numbers)+1,
 MID(letters,indices+5-XLOOKUP(numbers,unique,freq),1)
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`CHAR(97)` outputs "a;" subsequent letters can be output by incrementing upwards. Careful use of relative references can be a quick fix. Dragging `=CHAR(96 + COUNTIFS(A$1:A1, A1))` down should adjust the range to only the cells above the row being calculated.

Otherwise, you ran use `FILTER` and `ROW` to create a more robust solution, although it will take longer to calculate due to the use of dynamic array formulas.

`=CHAR(96 + COUNTA(FILTER(A:A, (A:A=A1) * (ROW(A:A) <= ROW()))))`